# Excel - Hyperlink to another sheet based on specific text value

Tags: excel, hyperlink, formulas

I am working on a Maintenance document of customers to which Column A is the customer names and column O is named 'Invoice History. Within Column O I want to create a hyperlink which links to a different sheet in the same workbook named 'Invoice History',however I want it to jump to the row the same customer in column A in the main sheet is.

Is this possible without a VBA? I seem to be going in circles!

Cheers - OJW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I've understood your requirements, yes this is possible without [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)
 - modify this as needed to reflect your workbook name and the column the customer names are in on the "Invoice History" sheet.

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book2.xlsx]'Invoice History'!A"&MATCH(A2,'Invoice History'!A:A,0),A2 & " Link")
```

where:

- `[Book2.xlsx]` is the name of your workbook.
- The customer names are in Column A on the "Invoice History" tab.

[image]